# WAMP Server 2.1 won't start when using php_mssql?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sql-server

I have the lastest stable Wamp Server running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) box. I'm trying to run PHP 5.2.11 for an old site. 5.2.11 works just fine in WAMP Server until I enable the PHP_MSSQL extension, apache no longer starts. Disabling php_mssql in php.ini fixes it. Apache DOES however start if I run an older version of PHP with php_mssql on; however the old version has unacceptable query times, 20x longer for some queries.

Is there any reason this might not work? It's only the php_mssql plugin. I tried to find the latest but was unsuccessful; I know the php_sqlsrv.dll extension is superior, however I'm using an old version of cake and I need php_mssql to use their drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, the php_mssql version was broken. Used an older version that shipped with php 5.2.9 and it did work.